# Pandas to_csv is excluding rows from my target variable

Tags: python, pandas, csv, scikit-learn

I'm using a simple RandomForestRegressor script to predict a target variable. I'm trying to write a new CSV based on my training / validation data to include the actual value and the predicted value. However, when I export the data, the "Predicted Values" column is missing about half the values, and the values that do show up don't correlate well with the features / actual values. It seems like the values are randomized and then assigned to the first half of the rows.

To test, I've tried not splitting the data between validation and training data in the first place. I'm still finding the same problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#file path
My_File_Path = "//path.csv"
#read the file
My_Data = pd.read_csv(My_File_Path)
#drop the null values
My_Data = My_Data.dropna(axis=0)

#define the target variable
y = My_Data.Annualized_2018_Payments
my_features = ['feature1','feature2','feature3']
#define the features
x = My_Data[my_features]

#set the split data
train_x, val_x, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(x, y, random_state = 1)

forest_model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 1)
forest_model.fit(train_x, train_y)
WA_My_preds = forest_model.predict(val_x)
print("MAE for validation data is ", mean_absolute_error(val_y, WA_My_preds))

#print(My_Data.columns)

My_Data_Predicted = My_Data

#My_Data_Predicted.append(prediction_column, ignore_index = False, sort=None)
My_Data_Predicted['Predicted_Value'] = pd.DataFrame(data = forest_model.predict(My_Data_Predicted[my_features]))
print("The average predicted value is ", My_Data_Predicted['Predicted_Value'].mean())
print("The average true value is ", My_Data_Predicted['Annualized_2018_Payments'].mean())
#write to csv
My_Data_Predicted.to_csv("//path….Preds.csv")
```

I expect every row to have a column that reads "predicted values" with the values predicted by the random forest regressor. But the last half of the rows are missing that value.

Comment: Update: I tried remapping and reloading the data after fitting the model, but that didn't seem to fix the issue.

My_File_Path1 = "...data.csv"
#read the file
My_Data1 = pd.read_csv(My_File_Path1)
#drop the null values
My_Data1 = My_Data1.dropna(axis=0)

My_Data_Predicted = My_Data1

Comment: Thank you for those recommended updates to my syntax (e.g. the format of the open quotes and the … on the file path). I used pseudo-code for this part; I'm primarily having trouble with the logic.

Answer (score 0):

## For a short answer and resolution:

Based on testing your code, you should try this line instead:

```
My_Data_Predicted['Predicted_Value'] = forest_model.predict(My_Data_Predicted[my_features])
```

---

## And now Here's why this is happening:

I tested this using my own dataset and it looks like the issue is this line:

```
My_Data_Predicted['Predicted_Value'] = pd.DataFrame(data = forest_model.predict(My_Data_Predicted[my_features]))
```

What is happening, it would seem, is that when you drop the null rows here:

```
My_Data = My_Data.dropna(axis=0)
```

you are also dropping the indexes along with the rows, which is not wrong, but important for your issue. To test this, try `My_Data_Predicted.index.max()` to get the highest index and compare that to `My_Data_Predicted.shape` and you will see that there are skipped indexes.

The reason this is a problem is that by making your predicted column a dataframe instead of a series, it is automatically trying to merge the new data based on indexes. The issue is that the original dataframe has a higher max index with some gaps, and this new one for predictions has sequential indexes, so some of your predictions are getting dropped in the process of merging.

Here is a dumbed down example of whats going on (pay attention to the indexes):

```
My_Data_Predicted     predictions      My_Data_Predicted (merged)
index  a  b  c          index  d            index  a  b  c  d
  0    1  4  3            0    1              0    1  4  3  1
  3    3  2  7            1    2              3    3  2  7  4
  4    2  2  2            2    3              4    2  2  2  5
  6    4  3  5            3    4              6    4  3  5  NaN
  8    6  2  1            4    5              8    6  2  1  NaN
```

Notice that in the merged dataframe the last two are `NaN` because there is no index 6 or 8 in the predictions dataframe.

All of this should resolve by passing in the result if the predictions just like this:

```
My_Data_Predicted['Predicted_Value'] = forest_model.predict(My_Data_Predicted[my_features])
```

since the type is a numpy array and will not try to merge on the index.